# Hovering button causes window to close

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jbutton

I'm developing a program that's meant to open a mode-less window whenever I hover some specific component. I'm not going into details that are not necessary but basically I have a mouse listener that opens a JFrame and shows a picture. The problem is, I also want to have a button that's meant to change the picture, but whenever I hover the button, the window closes and I have no idea why.
Here's the code:
Listener call:

```
public class ImageAction extends FocusOwnerAction{

/**
 * The user interface controller
 */
protected UIController uiController;

public ImageAction(UIController uiController) {

    this.uiController = uiController;

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        MouseHoverController mouse = new MouseHoverController(focusOwner, this.focusOwner.getSpreadsheet());
        mouse.addMouseHoverEvent();

}
```

...

```
public class MouseHoverController {

private final JTable table;
private final Spreadsheet spread;

public MouseHoverController(JTable table, Spreadsheet spread) {
    this.table = table;
    this.spread = spread;
}

public void addMouseHoverEvent() {
    MouseHoverEvent mouseEvent = new MouseHoverEvent(spread);
    table.addMouseMotionListener((MouseMotionListener) mouseEvent);
}
}
```

...

```
public class MouseHoverEvent extends MouseMotionAdapter {

private Spreadsheet spreadsheet;

public MouseHoverEvent(Spreadsheet spreadsheet) {
    this.spreadsheet = spreadsheet;
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    final JTable aTable = (JTable) e.getSource();
    int itsRow = aTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
    int itsColumn = aTable.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
    Cell c = this.spreadsheet.getCell(itsColumn, itsRow);

    ImageCell choosedCell = (ImageCell) c.getExtension(ImageExtension.NAME);
    if (choosedCell.hasImages()) {
        aTable.removeMouseMotionListener(this);


        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("path.png");
        Image im = img.getImage();
        Image newimg = im.getScaledInstance(400, 500, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon imgResizable = new ImageIcon(newimg);
        JLabel image = new JLabel(imgResizable);
        JPanel picPanel = new JPanel();
        picPanel.add(image);
        frame.add(picPanel);
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Next");
        frame.add(b1);
        frame.setSize(400, 500);

        // here's the part where I center the jframe on screen
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.dispose();
                MouseHoverEvent mouseEvent = new MouseHoverEvent(spreadsheet);
                aTable.addMouseMotionListener((MouseMotionListener) mouseEvent);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }

}

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"whenever I hover the button, the window closes and I have no idea why."* well `public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { frame.dispose();` would **likely** have a large part to do with it. (For more tan 'likely' post an MCVE.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson , I know that has to do with that. But that is meant to trigger when the cursor leaves the frame, not when enters one of it's components. With some tries, I've noticed that that happens to components that have a function, like buttons or even labels that override the mouse listener.

Comment: *"I know that has to do with that."* OK.. and what are you doing to correct the problem? I'd check the bounds of the frame and check if the mouse event is within that bounds, if so, do nothing, if not, dispose the frame. But if you need more help than that, post an MCVE like I advised 11 hours ago.